# how to return many values in mysql_fetch_array php

Tags: php, arrays, return

I want to get the first_name and the last_name from a database.
I select them, but then I'm unable to return both with a space in-between them, and need it to be returned not echoed because I am going to use it as a link for the user profile.

```
function getuser ($id, $field_one, $field_two) {
$query = mysql_query("SELECT $field_one, $field_two FROM users WHERE user_id='$id'");
$run = mysql_fetch_array($query);
return $run[$field_one, $field_two];

}
```

I think the problem is in the last 2 lines

```
$run = mysql_fetch_array($query);
return $run[$field_one];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
return $run[$field_one] . " " . $run[$field_two];
```

BTW you have to change your query to:

```
"SELECT {$field_one}, {$field_two} FROM users WHERE user_id={$id}"
```

Take a look at this for examples: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Answer (score 0):

If you always need the full name you might use something like `SELECT CONCAT(firstname, " ", lastname) as fullname FROM table` already in your SQL.